# Docker compose use same php version between containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, codeception

i have nginx php and codecept containers that are connected with docker compose, when im running the codecept container i noticed that it gets php version 7.4 while in my php container im running php 8 and a lot of the packages depends on php 8 so it fails to launch.

Is it possible to make codecept run php off my container ?
Or is it possible to set codecept to run the same php version ?

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/nginx
      args:
        NGINX_VERSION: latest
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html:cached
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - my-network
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - php
  codecept:
    image: codeception/codeception
    container_name: codeception
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./html:/project
    networks:
      - my-network
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/php
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: 8.0.10
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    networks:
      - my-network
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html:cached

networks:
  my-network: null
```

Answer (score 1):

The prebuilt codeception Docker image comes with a pre-installed PHP version, see https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/4.1/Dockerfile

So you might consider building your own codeception image with the desired PHP version, if needed.

Comment: Thank you, i did not realise that.. i built my own codeception image right now and it seems to work!

Comment: @PhilipCodeX may I know how did you managed to push the php version inside your dockerfile? I am facing same challenge  in one of my docker-compose, php , laravel setup.

Comment: @PhilipCodeX It's the first line in the Dockerfile:

`FROM php:7.4-cli`